# Validate Google Account using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying validate Google Account using WebClient.

```
class PostDataBuilder 
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> 
        ToPropertyDictionary(object data) 
    { 
        var values = data
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new { 
                                Key = x.Name, 
                                Value = x.GetValue(data, null) 
                             });

        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in values)
            result.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());

        return result;
    }

    public static string Build(object data)
    {
        string result = "";
        var dict = ToPropertyDictionary(data);
        foreach (var name in dict.Keys)
            result += name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(dict[name]) + "&";
        return result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string postText = PostDataBuilder.Build(
        new
        {
            dsh = "-1903339439726094408",
            GALX = "-Ggrv6gqusk",
            timeStmp = "",
            secTok = "",
            Email = "WrongEmail@gmail.com",
            Passwd = "WrongPassword",
            signIn = "?????",
            rmShown = "1"
        });

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postText);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] result = wc.UploadData(
            new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"), 
            "POST", data);

        string resultText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

ResultText variable has setted , even if data is correct. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ever screw around with login services such as the Google one or try to fake a browser. In the end it could be considered attempt hacking or whatever and it's very likely to break the next time they update their page (or even just because your IP changes).

Instead use OpenID or OAuth as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/GettingStarted).